# How can I search matching string from a list

Tags: c#

```cs
public Dictionary<string, Student> enrolledStudentsList1 = new Dictionary<string, Student>();

        public Student SearchByGroup(string groupName)
        {
            if (enrolledStudentsList1.ContainsKey(groupName))
            {
                return enrolledStudentsList1[groupName];
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void btnSearchStudentGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //listBoxStudents.Items.Clear();
            Student student = course.SearchByGroup(Convert.ToString(tbStudentSearchGroup.Text));
            if (student != null)
            {
                    listBoxStudents.Items.Add(student);
            }
        }
```

so im trying to make a button that searches a string groupName in the list.
What the method does is when I type a string in the textbox and press the button, it suppose to look for a matching string in the list of students and shows it to the listbox.

apparently the button does nothing which I cant see where the problem is.

Comment: [What is debugging?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/what-is-debugging?view=vs-2022)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the beginning of your `btnSearchStudentGroup_Click` routine. Does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.